# Unable to run script file from nodejs cmd

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm new to nodejs. I've a file called `main.js` with following code.

```
var http = require("http");
http.createServer(function (request, response) {
   response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
   response.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(8080);
console.log('Server running at http://localhost:8080/');
```

I'm trying to run my `main.js` file using nodejs cli. But got a syntax error.

> SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Command that I'm using to run `main.js` file is:

```
$ node main.js
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: no errors to me,the console should give you the exact row and column of the error

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Sadly your example doesn't reproduce the error you've given.

Comment: Yes, not getting any error in console and in browser also getiing the response "Hello World".

Comment: Re install **nodejs** again and check **path** in environment variable

Comment: When I'm using Command Prompt it works for me too. But when trying to run with nodejs  cmd it throw error. :(

Comment: @ankit You're going to need to give more information. We can't help you otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the error you are talking about.

[image]

**Well node.exe is not meant to execute files.**

### It is for executing inline script and code blocks.

You should open CMD and run

```
node main.js
```

And it will work fine

If you open the `node.exe` file in the folder and in the console if you try to run a file, it is error because

#### It will treat `main.js` as a variable(identifier).

and it is undefined.

Comment: Yeah! This is the error what i'm getting. So as you say, it is not possible to run file from nodejs cmd?

Comment: it is just a cli to run inline code. you should use system cmd to execute file

Comment: Thanks for your help @Sagar V :) .

Answer (score 0):

This program is fine. I even tested in on old Node version v0.10.

Node never gives you just "SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier" as you quoted.

This is an example of that error - if you use:

```
x x;
```

then you'll get:

```
/home/rsp/node/test/node-cmd/xx.js:2
x x;
  ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at createScript (vm.js:53:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:95:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:543:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:605:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:423:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:147:9)
```

Note that it gives you the exact line and character and file name where that error happened. You didn't provide it here so all I can tell you is to see the full error and read it carefully as it will tell you what exactly caused the error.

If you had included the entire error message together with the source code that caused the problem then we might have given you a more specific answer.

Comment: the problem is clear from one of his comment to the question. see my answer